# v-usb with default arduino bootloader on ATMega328

Tags: arduino, usb, atmega, bootloader

I've been trying to figure out how to use v-usb on an ATMega328P but pretty much all the tutorials I've found are for ATTiny or use the ATMega328P but use a modified bootloader. I don't actually care at all about being able to program the chip over this USB connection and would rather just use the FTDI connection. I just want to have USB HID capability once the sketch starts.

Does anyone know how to use v-usb and still have complete compatibility with Arduino and use its default bootloader??

**Edit:** The bootloader issue may be moot. It may just work with the default. In that case, great. But I would still love to be pointed to something that shows exactly how to setup the hardware and firmware to get v-usb working on an ATMega.

Comment: Have you tried ignoring the bootloader completely?

Comment: Ignoring it as in not using it? Or just not worrying about it and trying the code anyways? I do need some sort of bootloader.

Comment: The bootloader uses separate resources from the rest of the flash code.

Comment: Then forget the bootloader... just need v-usb to work with an ATMega328P

Comment: The ATtinyX5 doesn't have a bootloader, so start there.

Answer (score 1):

[vusb-for-arduino](https://code.google.com/p/vusb-for-arduino/)
This is actually quite an old project (it works with arduino 0020)
but it can be used as a good reference
and probably easily ported to the newer IDE

Also look [here](http://www.hackster.io/rayburne/arduino-to-excel-using-v-usb) its a newer project but it only has keyboard